# (Flutter) ListView.builder with a TextField and TextEditingController desync behavior

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

I'm getting a desync behavior with ListView.builder, TextField, and TextEditingController.
When I'm adding/removing an "issue" object the text that I see once I tap the issue is "shifted" one down or just way wrong, but the controller still affects the same object.
I'm adding pictures for clarification:

So here you can see all the objects

[image: picture 1]

Once i tap say the first top one "5"

[image]

Now i add an new "issue" object

[image]

Then i click again on the object i clicked before "5" which is the second top one now:

[image]

I cant seem to understand why this behavoir happens and how to fix it.
finally im posting my code for more refrense:

```dart
// ignore_for_file: non_constant_identifier_names, sized_box_for_whitespace
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:dronebag/app.dart';
import 'package:dronebag/config/font_size.dart';
import 'package:dronebag/domain/battery_issue_repository/battery_issue_repository.dart';
import 'package:dronebag/domain/battery_repository/battery_repository.dart';
import 'package:dronebag/domain/battery_station_issue_repository/battery_station_issue_repository.dart';
import 'package:dronebag/domain/battery_station_repository/src/models/models.dart';
import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import '../widgets/widgest.dart';

class BatteryStationDetails extends StatefulWidget {
  final String groupID;
  final BatteryStation batteryStation;
  const BatteryStationDetails({
    Key? key,
    required this.groupID,
    required this.batteryStation,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<BatteryStationDetails> createState() => _BatteryStationDetailsState();
}

class _BatteryStationDetailsState extends State<BatteryStationDetails> {
  final formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final TextEditingController serial_numberController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController batteryIssueDetailController =
      TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController batteryCycleController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController date_boughtController = TextEditingController();
  final double sizedBoxHight = 16;
  final TextEditingController battery_pairsController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    // ignore: todo
    // TODO: implement initState

    super.initState();
  }



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final fetch = FirestoreFetch(
        groupID: widget.groupID, batteryStation: widget.batteryStation);
    final create = FirestoreCreate(
        groupID: widget.groupID, batteryStation: widget.batteryStation);
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: ThemeColors.scaffoldBgColor,
          title: Text(
            "Battery Station ${widget.batteryStation.serial_number}",
            style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
              color: ThemeColors.whiteTextColor,
              fontSize: FontSize.xxLarge,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
            ),
          ),
          actions: [
            TextButton(
              child: Text(
                'Edit Station \nDetails',
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  fontSize: FontSize.medium,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                ),
              ),
              onPressed: () {
                showDialog(
                    context: context,
                    builder: (context) => EditBatteryStationDialog(
                          batteryStation: widget.batteryStation,
                          groupID: widget.groupID,
                        ));
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(38),
            child: Column(children: [
              Text(
                'Batteries',
                style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                  color: ThemeColors.textFieldHintColor,
                  fontSize: FontSize.large,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                ),
              ),
              StreamBuilder<List<Battery>>(
                  stream: fetch.fetchBatteries(),
                  builder: ((context, snapshot) {
                    if (snapshot.hasData) {
                      final batteries = snapshot.data!;
                      batteries.sort(
                        (a, b) {
                          return a.serial_number.compareTo(b.serial_number);
                        },
                      );
                      return GridView.builder(
                        physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                        gridDelegate:
                            const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                          crossAxisCount: 2,
                          childAspectRatio: 1.8,
                        ),
                        itemCount: batteries.length,
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          return BatteryTile(
                              battery: batteries[index],
                              batteryStation: widget.batteryStation,
                              groupID: widget.groupID);
                        },
                      );
                    } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                      return SingleChildScrollView(
                        child: Text('Something went wrong! \n\n$snapshot',
                            style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
                      );
                    } else {
                      return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                    }
                  })),
              const SizedBox(height: 20),
              RichText(
                text: TextSpan(
                  children: [
                    TextSpan(
                      style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                        color: ThemeColors.textFieldHintColor,
                        fontSize: FontSize.large,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                      ),
                      text: "Station\'s Issue list ",
                    ),
                    const WidgetSpan(
                        child: Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 20, 0),
                    )),
                    TextSpan(
                      recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer()
                        ..onTap = () {
                          create.createBatteryStationIssue();
                        },
                      text: 'Add Issue',
                      style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                        color: ThemeColors.primaryColor,
                        fontSize: FontSize.medium,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 12),
//vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvRELEVENTvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv//
              StreamBuilder<List<BatteryStationIssue>>(
                stream: fetch.fetchBatteryStationIssue(),
                builder: ((context, snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.hasData) {
                    final batteryStationIssues = snapshot.data!;
                    //print(issues.length);
                    return Container(
                      child: ListView.builder(
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                        itemCount: batteryStationIssues.length,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          print("==========");
                          return BatteryStationIssueTile(
                              groupID: widget.groupID,
                              batteryStation: widget.batteryStation,
                              batteryStationIssue: batteryStationIssues[index]);
                        },
                      ),
                    );
                  } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                    return SingleChildScrollView(
                      child: Text('Something went wrong! \n\n$snapshot',
                          style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
                    );
                  } else {
                    return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                  }
                }),
              ),
            ]),
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

```dart
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:dronebag/config/font_size.dart';
import 'package:dronebag/config/theme_colors.dart';
import 'package:dronebag/domain/battery_station_issue_repository/battery_station_issue_repository.dart';
import 'package:dronebag/domain/battery_station_repository/battery_station_repository.dart';
import 'package:dronebag/widgets/utils.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';

class BatteryStationIssueTile extends StatefulWidget {
  final String groupID;
  final BatteryStation batteryStation;
  final BatteryStationIssue batteryStationIssue;
  const BatteryStationIssueTile({
    Key? key,
    required this.groupID,
    required this.batteryStation,
    required this.batteryStationIssue,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<BatteryStationIssueTile> createState() =>
      _BatteryStationIssueTileState();
}

class _BatteryStationIssueTileState extends State<BatteryStationIssueTile> {
  TextEditingController batteryStationIssueDetailController =
      TextEditingController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    
    batteryStationIssueDetailController =
        TextEditingController(text: widget.batteryStationIssue.detail);
    super.initState();
    
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    batteryStationIssueDetailController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    String issueDescription = widget.batteryStationIssue.detail;
    Color textDescriptionColor = ThemeColors.whiteTextColor;
    if (widget.batteryStationIssue.detail == "") {
      issueDescription = "Click me to add description";
      textDescriptionColor = ThemeColors.greyTextColor;
    }
    print("Issue:");
    print(widget.batteryStationIssue.detail);
    return ListTile(
      onTap: (() {
        showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
            backgroundColor: ThemeColors.scaffoldBgColor,
            scrollable: true,
            title: Center(
              child: Text(
                "Edit issue description",
                style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                  color: ThemeColors.whiteTextColor,
                  fontSize: FontSize.large,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            content: TextFormField(
              controller: batteryStationIssueDetailController,
              keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
              maxLines: null,
              style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                color: ThemeColors.whiteTextColor,
                fontSize: FontSize.medium,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
              ),
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                fillColor: ThemeColors.textFieldBgColor,
                filled: true,
                hintText: "Issue description",
                hintStyle: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                  color: ThemeColors.textFieldHintColor,
                  fontSize: FontSize.small,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                ),
                border: const OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(18)),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            actions: [
              TextButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.pop(context);
                  },
                  child: const Text('Cancel')),
              TextButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    final docBatteryStationIssue = FirebaseFirestore.instance
                        .collection('groups')
                        .doc(widget.groupID)
                        .collection('battery_stations')
                        .doc(widget.batteryStation.id)
                        .collection('issues')
                        .doc(widget.batteryStationIssue.id);
                    docBatteryStationIssue.update(
                        {'detail': batteryStationIssueDetailController.text});
                    Navigator.pop(context);
                    Utils.showSnackBarWithColor(
                        'Issue has been updated', Colors.blue);
                  },
                  child: const Text(
                    'Update issue',
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue),
                  )),
            ],
          ),
        );
      }),
      title: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
        child: Container(
          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
              color: Color.fromARGB(255, 32, 32, 32),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5))),
          child: Center(
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8, 5, 8, 5),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                    child: Text(
                      '${widget.batteryStationIssue.date.day}-${widget.batteryStationIssue.date.month}-${widget.batteryStationIssue.date.year}',
                      style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                        color: ThemeColors.whiteTextColor,
                        fontSize: FontSize.medium,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                    child: Text(
                      issueDescription,
                      style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                        color: textDescriptionColor,
                        fontSize: FontSize.medium,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: [
                      Align(
                        alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                        child: Text(
                          'Status:  ${widget.batteryStationIssue.status}',
                          style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                            color: ThemeColors.whiteTextColor,
                            fontSize: FontSize.medium,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Align(
                        alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                        child: IconButton(
                          iconSize: 24,
                          splashColor: Colors.transparent,
                          color: Colors.red,
                          icon: const Icon(Icons.delete),
                          onPressed: () {
                            showDialog(
                              context: context,
                              builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
                                  backgroundColor: ThemeColors.scaffoldBgColor,
                                  title: Center(
                                    child: Text(
                                      "Delete this issue?",
                                      style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                                        color: ThemeColors.whiteTextColor,
                                        fontSize: FontSize.large,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  actions: [
                                    TextButton(
                                        onPressed: () {
                                          Navigator.pop(context);
                                        },
                                        child: const Text(
                                          'Cancle',
                                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue),
                                        )),
                                    TextButton(
                                        onPressed: () {
                                          FirebaseFirestore.instance
                                              .collection('groups')
                                              .doc(widget.groupID)
                                              .collection('battery_stations')
                                              .doc(widget.batteryStation.id)
                                              .collection("issues")
                                              .doc(
                                                  widget.batteryStationIssue.id)
                                              .delete();
                                          Navigator.pop(context);
                                        },
                                        child: const Text(
                                          'Yes Delete',
                                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
                                        )),
                                  ]),
                            );
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: what is `EditBatteryStationDialog`? you probably should put the controller there.

Comment: you can ignore `EditBatteryStationDialog` I don't think it's relevant to the case.